# Getting error while installing lme4 package in R in MacOSX Monterey

Tags: r, homebrew

I am getting the following error when trying to install the `lme4` package in R.

```
install.packages("lme4")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘minqa’

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/minqa_1.2.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 53548 bytes (52 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 52 KB

trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-29.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3306026 bytes (3.2 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.2 MB

* installing *source* package ‘minqa’ ...
** package ‘minqa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c altmov.f -o altmov.o
altmov.f:42:72:

   42 |    10 HCOL(K)=ZERO
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 10 at (1)
altmov.f:45:72:

   45 |       DO 20 K=1,NPT
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 20 at (1)
altmov.f:46:72:

   46 |    20 HCOL(K)=HCOL(K)+TEMP*ZMAT(K,J)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 20 at (1)
altmov.f:53:72:

   53 |    30 GLAG(I)=BMAT(KNEW,I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 30 at (1)
altmov.f:57:72:

   57 |    40 TEMP=TEMP+XPT(K,J)*XOPT(J)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 40 at (1)
altmov.f:59:72:

   59 |       DO 50 I=1,N
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 50 at (1)
altmov.f:60:72:

   60 |    50 GLAG(I)=GLAG(I)+TEMP*XPT(K,I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 50 at (1)
altmov.f:76:72:

   76 |    60 DISTSQ=DISTSQ+TEMP*TEMP
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 60 at (1)
altmov.f:172:72:

  172 |    90 XNEW(I)=DMAX1(SL(I),DMIN1(SU(I),TEMP))
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 90 at (1)
altmov.f:237:72:

  237 |   140 GW=GW+GLAG(I)*W(I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 140 at (1)
altmov.f:248:72:

  248 |   150 TEMP=TEMP+XPT(K,J)*W(J)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 150 at (1)
altmov.f:249:72:

  249 |   160 CURV=CURV+HCOL(K)*TEMP*TEMP
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 160 at (1)
altmov.f:255:72:

  255 |   170     XALT(I)=DMAX1(SL(I),DMIN1(SU(I),TEMP))
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 170 at (1)
altmov.f:268:72:

  268 |   180     W(N+I)=XALT(I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 180 at (1)
altmov.f:275:72:

  275 |   190     XALT(I)=W(N+I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 190 at (1)
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-x86-pad-for-align=false'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '--x86-slh-loads=false'?
make: *** [altmov.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/minqa’
ERROR: dependency ‘minqa’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/lme4’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/02/6dwz1gvd1qz4gml8v_wv6n980000gp/T/RtmpVREiYV/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("lme4") :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
```

I recently upgraded my OS to MacOSX Monterey (12.3.1) in a MacBook 2020 (intel chip).

I have tried reinstalling `gcc` and `gccfortran` using `brew` with no effect.

Can anyone help me with the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing `xcode` command line tools and reinstalling it solved the issue.

```
$ xcode-select --print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install
```