# Issue installing `gamm4` for R v4.2.2

Tags: r, package

I'm having issues installing the package `gamm4` with R v4.2.2. It seems to fail because of the required package `minqa` (see `ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’` below). `minqa` is not listed as a requirement on the [gamm4 package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=gamm4), but maybe it is a requirement for one of the other required packages? Anyway, I'm not sure how to debug this, and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!

Here's the session info and detail log:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin21.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.6.1

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/local/Cellar/openblas/0.3.21/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.dylib
LAPACK: /usr/local/Cellar/r/4.2.2/lib/R/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
[1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.2 tools_4.2.2
```

```
> install.packages('gamm4')
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependencies ‘minqa’, ‘lme4’

trying URL 'https://cran.case.edu/src/contrib/minqa_1.2.5.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 54415 bytes (53 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 53 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.case.edu/src/contrib/lme4_1.1-31.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2947739 bytes (2.8 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 2.8 MB

trying URL 'https://cran.case.edu/src/contrib/gamm4_0.2-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 14969 bytes (14 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 14 KB

* installing *source* package ‘minqa’ ...
** package ‘minqa’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
/usr/local/opt/gcc/bin/gfortran -fno-optimize-sibling-calls  -fPIC  -g -O2  -c altmov.f -o altmov.o
altmov.f:42:72:

   42 |    10 HCOL(K)=ZERO
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 10 at (1)
altmov.f:45:72:

   45 |       DO 20 K=1,NPT
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 20 at (1)
altmov.f:46:72:

   46 |    20 HCOL(K)=HCOL(K)+TEMP*ZMAT(K,J)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 20 at (1)
altmov.f:53:72:

   53 |    30 GLAG(I)=BMAT(KNEW,I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 30 at (1)
altmov.f:57:72:

   57 |    40 TEMP=TEMP+XPT(K,J)*XOPT(J)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 40 at (1)
altmov.f:59:72:

   59 |       DO 50 I=1,N
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: Shared DO termination label 50 at (1)
altmov.f:60:72:

   60 |    50 GLAG(I)=GLAG(I)+TEMP*XPT(K,I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 50 at (1)
altmov.f:76:72:

   76 |    60 DISTSQ=DISTSQ+TEMP*TEMP
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 60 at (1)
altmov.f:173:72:

  173 |    90 XNEW(I)=DMAX1(SL(I),DMIN1(SU(I),TEMP))
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 90 at (1)
altmov.f:238:72:

  238 |   140 GW=GW+GLAG(I)*W(I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 140 at (1)
altmov.f:249:72:

  249 |   150 TEMP=TEMP+XPT(K,J)*W(J)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 150 at (1)
altmov.f:250:72:

  250 |   160 CURV=CURV+HCOL(K)*TEMP*TEMP
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 160 at (1)
altmov.f:256:72:

  256 |   170     XALT(I)=DMAX1(SL(I),DMIN1(SU(I),TEMP))
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 170 at (1)
altmov.f:269:72:

  269 |   180     W(N+I)=XALT(I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 180 at (1)
altmov.f:276:72:

  276 |   190     XALT(I)=W(N+I)
      |                                                                        1
Warning: Fortran 2018 deleted feature: DO termination statement which is not END DO or CONTINUE with label 190 at (1)
clang (LLVM option parsing): Unknown command line argument '-x86-pad-for-align=false'.  Try: 'clang (LLVM option parsing) --help'
clang (LLVM option parsing): Did you mean '--x86-slh-loads=false'?
make: *** [altmov.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘minqa’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/minqa’
ERROR: dependency ‘minqa’ is not available for package ‘lme4’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/lme4’
ERROR: dependency ‘lme4’ is not available for package ‘gamm4’
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/4.2/site-library/gamm4’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/2q/qbb1m4q52md022yt2cqbd9mm0000gn/T/RtmpYkdEv8/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("gamm4") :
  installation of package ‘minqa’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("gamm4") :
  installation of package ‘lme4’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages("gamm4") :
  installation of package ‘gamm4’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Based on your `sessionInfo()`, first thing to try is installing a 'fresh' gfortran (https://github.com/fxcoudert/gfortran-for-macOS/releases) and trying `install.packages("gamm4")` again, then if you get the same issue, these steps should solve your problem (requires a fair amount of time/effort): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65251887/clang-7-error-linker-command-failed-with-exit-code-1-for-macos-big-sur/65334247#65334247.

Comment: [Getting error while installing lme4 package in R in MacOSX Monterey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72409270/getting-error-while-installing-lme4-package-in-r-in-macosx-monterey)
Similar errors in the question above. In that case, gFortran reinstall did not help, but xcode reinstall did.
` $ xcode-select --print-path
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ sudo rm -r -f /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
$ xcode-select --install`

Comment: gamm4 depends on lme4, which imports minqa. Minqa imports Rcpp. I've had to reinstall Rcpp to resolve package installation issues before.